# Google's object detection API error when using model from laptop in Raspberry PI 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, object-detection

I have implemented Google's Object detection API (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) on both my laptop and on a Raspberry PI model 3. I have managed to train a model and run the test code to make a prediction separately on both the PI and my laptop.

But the PI is obviously slow and training a good model would take forever, so I want to train the model on my laptop and then transfer the necessary files to the PI for prediction. However, when I do this I get the following error(when running object_detection_tutorial.ipynb from the github directory inside jupyter on the PI):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1322     try:
-> 1323       return fn(*args)
   1324     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1301                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1302                                    status, run_metadata)
   1303 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'index_type' not in Op<name=Fill; signature=dims:int32, value:T -> output:T; attr=T:type>; NodeDef: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones = Fill[T=DT_INT32, index_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/Reshape, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/delta). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
     [[Node: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones = Fill[T=DT_INT32, index_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/Reshape, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/delta)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-dca1b88151c5> in <module>()
      7   image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      8   # Actual detection.
----> 9   output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
     10   # Visualization of the results of a detection.
     11   vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(

<ipython-input-9-f22e65a052c1> in run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph)
     33       # Run inference
     34       output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
---> 35                              feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
     36 
     37       # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1119       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1121     else:
   1122       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1315     if handle is None:
   1316       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1317                            options, run_metadata)
   1318     else:
   1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1334         except KeyError:
   1335           pass
-> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1337 
   1338   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'index_type' not in Op<name=Fill; signature=dims:int32, value:T -> output:T; attr=T:type>; NodeDef: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones = Fill[T=DT_INT32, index_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/Reshape, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/delta). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
     [[Node: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones = Fill[T=DT_INT32, index_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/Reshape, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/delta)]]

Caused by op 'MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-0d8b8f2357e8>", line 7, in <module>
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 411, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3069, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1579, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NodeDef mentions attr 'index_type' not in Op<name=Fill; signature=dims:int32, value:T -> output:T; attr=T:type>; NodeDef: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones = Fill[T=DT_INT32, index_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/Reshape, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/delta). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
     [[Node: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/ones = Fill[T=DT_INT32, index_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Meshgrid/ExpandedShape/Reshape, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/delta)]]
```

Additional information:

On my laptop I am running Windows 10 and running tensorflow in an Anaconda environment. Python version: 3.5.3. Tensorflow version: 1.5.0

On the Raspberry PI I am running Rasbian GNU/Linux version 9. Python version: 3.5.3. Tensorflow version 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem exactly was. It didn't work for me before because I exported the graph on my laptop, then sent the graph to the PI but this didnt work. So I sent over the files to the PI and then exported the graph there, then it worked.